# Cygwin key_load_public: invalid format

Tags: ssh, cygwin

I am using ssh to log in my host VM.
I tried using ubuntu subsystem embedded in win 10 and it works. But it failed when I am using the key pair to login with cygwin.

The errors and key formats are s follows:

```
$ ssh shdev@1.1.1.1 -v
OpenSSH_7.7p1, OpenSSL 1.0.2p  14 Aug 2018
debug1: Connecting to 1.1.1.1 port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
key_load_public: invalid format
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type -1
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.7
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: match: OpenSSH_6.6.1 pat OpenSSH_6.6.1* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Authenticating to 1.1.1.1:22 as 'shdev'
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-ed25519
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug1: Server host key: ssh-ed25519 SHA256:gCsQ1lK2+olxNndSQ4KqYxqF799KrltEeU+7UTK5wEI
debug1: Host '1.1.1.1' is known and matches the ED25519 host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/yilchen/.ssh/known_hosts:28
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug1: rekey after 134217728 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/yilchen/.ssh/id_rsa
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_dsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug1: Trying private key: /home/xxx/.ssh/id_xmss
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
shdev@1.1.1.1: Permission denied (publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic).
```

private key format:

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
...
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

public key format:

```
ssh-rsa
```

Comment: OpenSSH-6.6 is old. Upgrade to 8.0

Comment: You should run the verbose mode ssh connect from WSL and see exactly how it connects also. It's possible that whatever connection type it's using hasn't been configured in your Cygwin ssh, or that you're missing a file or setting related to that type of configuration. But since we don't know the specifics on what works for you it's hard to tell why the other doesn't work.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Breisch Above is the result run with -v, I am using a Ubuntu subsystem to log in remotely too but the Ubuntu one works. I just copied pasted the files from Ubuntu but it still fails.